# Unable To Override " getJsonSwatchConfig() " Method in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, swatches, overriding

I am working on magento 2 and want to override **getJsonSwatchConfig** method of `Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable` class to meet the requirement but facing an issue. I have overrided this method and this is working fine on product detail page but it does not work for  list page. I have debug with core file in both cases it loads same method. ie.  **getJsonSwatchConfig** but it does not override for list page. Codes are given below

**Namespace/modulename/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable" type="Namespace\modulename\Block\Magento\Swatches\Product\Renderer\Configurable" />
</config>
```

**Namespace\modulename\Block\Magento\Swatches\Product\Renderer\Configurable.php**

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\modulename\Block\Magento\Swatches\Product\Renderer;


class Configurable extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable
{
    /**
     * Get Swatch config data
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getJsonSwatchConfig()
    {
        echo $this->getProduct()->getTypeId() ." overrided = ".$this->getProduct()->getId(); exit;
        $attributesData = $this->getSwatchAttributesData();
        $allOptionIds = $this->getConfigurableOptionsIds($attributesData);
        $swatchesData = $this->swatchHelper->getSwatchesByOptionsId($allOptionIds);

        $config = [];
        foreach ($attributesData as $attributeId => $attributeDataArray) {
            if (isset($attributeDataArray['options'])) {
                $config[$attributeId] = $this->addSwatchDataForAttribute(
                    $attributeDataArray['options'],
                    $swatchesData,
                    $attributeDataArray
                );
            }
        }

        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($config);
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different block to load color swatch on list page and product detail page. Blocks are given blow

**For Product detail page**  - `Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable`

**For Category list page** - `Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable`

You are overriding only for product detail page because for list page `Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable` Class is used for swatch render. This class extend the magento core class instead of overrided Class

ie.

```
namespace Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing;

class Configurable extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable
```

So you have to override this class too with your class as follows

> di.xml

add following

```
<preference for="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" type="Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Magento\Swatches\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" />
```

> Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Magento\Swatches\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable

namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Magento\Swatches\Product\Renderer\Listing;

```
<?php 
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Magento\Swatches\Product\Renderer\Listing;

class Configurable extends \Namespace\ModuleName\Block\Magento\Swatches\Product\Renderer\Configurable
{


}
```

I think, This will help you.

Cheers !!!